# Location update on thread every few seconds on Android

Tags: android, location

Hi im trying to write a code to get the current location of the user. I have follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ closely and is working, however when i add in the thread code and i change the Lat and Lon from the extended controls in Android studio it refresh every 5 secs,  but the lat and lon still stays at 0.0 0.0

Below is the code with the thread

```
    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {

        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if(Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()) != null && Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()) != null){
                                    realLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                    realLongitude = gps.getLongitude();
                                    lblShowLat.setText(Double.toString(realLatitude));
                                    lblShowLon.setText(Double.toString(realLongitude));
                                    System.out.println(Double.toString(realLatitude) + " "+ Double.toString(realLongitude));

                                    updateDateTime();
                                }
                               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();

    }

    else
    {
        gps.showSettingAlert();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1)YOu can't get an updated location every 5s.  Your phone doesn't update location that frequently.  GPS is typically every 30s-1minute

2)That tutorial you're using is really broken.  That code should never be used, and every copy of it should be burned in flames.  I have a detailed breakdown of why that code is horrible here:  http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/   I also have a better way of doing it there.

3)The correct way for you to do this is to register for location updates, and update your server when your location updates rather than on a fixed schedule.

4)Without doing what's in 3, there's no way to make your code work.  Its relying on getLastKnownLocation, which may not may not work.  But if it isn't working at the beginning it will never fix itself.  The only safe use for that is using it optimistically as an optimization.  If you actually need a location you should always request updates, never expect that function to work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Sorry i'm still a beginner in android.. Could you assist and guide me along with it?